# problem with the evolution of an image on pylab

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, matrix

I'm creating a code illustrating the evolution of a fire in a wood. A code create a mathematical matrix with tuples RVB:

```
import numpy
from numpy import *
import pylab as pl
import random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

# colors :
sol = (128, 64, 0)
arbre = (0, 128, 32)
arbreprotege= (0,198,112)
ressourceprotegee=(130,100,20)
blanc = (255,255,255)
argent=(192,192,192)
gris=(128,128,128)
grisimmeuble=(182,182,182)
noir=(0,0,0)
jaune=(255,255,0)
jaunebis=(195,195,0)
jauneuniv=(240,250,0)
orange=(255,127,0)
orangebis=(250,150,0)
rouge=(255,0,0)
rose=(253,108,258)
magenta=(255,0,200)
violet=(127,0,255)
vertparc=(0,128,74)
vertclair=(0,250,0)
cyan=(0,255,255)
bleucanard=(4,169,154)
bleu=(0,0,250)
azur=(0,127,255)
marronferme=(110,124,20)
marronterraintennis=(200,60,0)
boisparc=(168,64,0)

ListCouleursBat=[blanc, argent, gris, grisimmeuble, noir, jaune, jaunebis, jauneuniv, orange, orangebis, rouge, rose, magenta, violet, vertclair, vertparc, cyan, bleucanard, bleu, azur, marronferme, marronterraintennis, boisparc]


def Initialise(n,p,t,c,r):
#n et p size of the matrix
#t probability or creating a tree
#c probability or creating a clear green tree
    R = zeros( (n,p), dtype=uint8 ) #le sol
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(p):
            x = rd.random()
            if x <= t:
                R[i,j] = 1   # trees
    for i in range(70,100):
      for j in range(60,100):
        d=rd.random()
        if d<=c:
          if R[i,j]==1:
            R[i,j]=10  # clear green trees
          else:
            R[i,j]=R[i,j]
    for i in range(10,40):
      for j in range(10,40):
        R[i,j]=0
        x=rd.random()
        if x<=r:
          R[i,j]=1
    for i in range(20,40):
        for j in range(80,90):
            R[i,j]=4       # géologic site
    return R


# creat the RVB matrix 
def Affiche(M):
    n,p = M.shape
    img = zeros( (n,p,3), dtype=uint8 ) 
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(p):
            if M[i, j] == 0:
                img[i,j,:] = sol # ground
            elif M[i,j]==1:
                img[i,j,:] = arbre # tree 
            elif M[i,j]==10 :
                img[i,j,:]=arbreprotege # clear green tree
            elif M[i,j]==4:
              img[i,j,:]=ressourceprotegee # geologic site
    return img

Mtest= Initialise(100, 100, 0.75,0.45,0.4)
M=Affiche(Mtest)
```

Then, a made a code which creates the beginning of the fire and one which checks if a burning tree is located near to the tree which is in the wood.
There are other codes which makes the evolution of the fire and show the burning matrix.

```
# change some trees into red pixels = the beginning of the fire
def DebutIncendie(M,t,s) : 
  n,p = 100,100
  nb = s
  for i in range (n) :
    for j in range (p) :
      if nb>0 :
        x = rd.random()
        if x <=t :
          M[i,j] = rouge
          nb -=1
  return M

# check if there is a burning tree near to the tree on the (i,j) position in the matrix
def Voisins(M,i,j,n,p,a): # i,j les coordonnées de l'arbre conserné, a la distence entre les arbres étudiés, n,p les dimensions de la matrice
    # on vérifie si la rangée d'arbres étudiée à la distance a existe bien dans la forêt (sinon la ligne i-a n'existe pas par exemple)
    if i >= a and j < p-a and j >= a :
        for l in range(j-a,j+1+a) :
            m=M[i-a,l]
            pix=(m[0],m[1],m[2])
            # un arbre au point (i-a,l) est en train de brûler si la valeur en ce point est 2,3 ou 5
            if pix == rouge or pix == orange or pix == jaune :
                return True
    if i < n-a and j < p-a and j >= a:
        for l in range(j-a, j+1+a) :
            m=M[i+a,l]
            pix=(m[0],m[1],m[2])
            if pix == rouge or pix == orange or pix == jaune :
                return True
    if j>=a and i>=a and i<n-a :
        for l in range (i-a,i+a+1) :
            m=M[l,j-a]
            pix=(m[0],m[1],m[2])
            if pix == rouge or pix == orange or pix == jaune :
                return True
    if j<p-a and i>=a and i<p-a :
        for l in range (i-a,i+a+1) :
            m=M[l,j+a]
            pix=(m[0],m[1],m[2])
            if pix == rouge or pix == orange or pix == jaune :
                return True
    #si aucun des arbres à la distance a de l'arbre étudié n'est en train de brûler, le programme rend False
    return False

# makes the evolution of the fire
def Evolution(M):
  global Em # ?
  R = copy(M)
  n,p = 100,100
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(p):
        r=R[i,j]
        pix=(r[0],r[1],r[2])
        m=M[i,j]
        el =(m[0],m[1],m[2])
        if pix == arbre or pix == arbreprotege:
            proba=0.6       # proba qu'il prenne feu
            for k in range(1,9): # on regarde autour de l'arbre et augmentant la distance à chaque tour (de 1 à 8)
                if pix==arbre or pix==arbreprotege: # seul les arbres peuvent brûler
                    if Voisins(M,i,j,n,p,k):
                        t=random.random()
                        if t<proba:
                            R[i,j]=rouge
                proba = proba - 0.05  # la probabilité de brûler diminue en fonction de la distance
        elif el ==rouge:
            pix = orange
        elif el == orange:
            pix = jaune
        elif el == jaune:
            pix = noir
  return R

def Feu(M): # check if there is burning trees in the wood so the fire can  go on
  n, p = 100,100
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(p):
        m=M[i,j]
        pix=(m[0],m[1],m[2])
        if pix == rouge :
            return True
        elif pix == orange :
            return True
        elif pix == jaune :
            return True
    return False

# shows the evolution of the fire in the wood
def ForetBrule(M):
  pl.ion()
  pl.figure(1)
  image = pl.imshow(M)
  pl.show()
  pl.pause(0.1)
  while pl.fignum_exists(1) and Feu(M):
    M = Evolution(M)
    image.set_data(M)
    image.changed()
    # pl.draw()
    pl.pause(0.1)
    pl.show()

M=DebutIncendie(M,0.005,50)
print(ForetBrule(M))
```

The code is working but it is very very very slow and my computer often crash. I don't fine the cause of this problem.
I hope you will find it.

Comment: It’s slow because you have many triple loops and python is slow with loops. You can likely get rid of almost all of these by using numpy and finding the matches in matrices.

Comment: I don(t see what you mean by finding the matches in matrices. Do you have any idea of which fonction I should create ?

Comment: If you simplify your question I could try.  But if you present the whole problem and all your code it’s hard to do anything but give general advice.